# Copernicus LTA products

Tags: python, download, copernicus, sentinel-3

I'm working with python and I have to download the whole year of Sentinel-3 data. I'm using sentinelsat library for download data. I have a question about downloading Long Term Archive (LTA) Copernicus products.

Can I make a request for a download for a whole year or can I only make requests for 1 product per 30 minutes?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this?  Can you provide a code snippet that illustrates how you tried to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/LongTermArchive

> A user quota on the maximum number of requests per hour per user is
> set. Products restored from the long term archives are kept online for a
> period of at least 3 days. Quota and keeping time will be fine tuned
> according to the usage patterns to ensure efficient access to the most
> recent and frequently downloaded data.

and

> The OData API returns an HTTP status code 202 Accepted when a
> request is successfully submitted to the LTA.
>
> The same code is provided also in case of product already requested by
> another user.

Did you try to make multiple requests? **I have never used LTA products in bulk**, but I would guess that it is not up to us to choose how many requests you can make.

If you just keep a script running (or schedule it) to make the requests and download in parallel (by using threading), I think this could save you much time